# Unity / Oculus : DLLNotFoundException OVRGamepad

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

Installing the latest Oculus Utilities package for Unity and dropping in a `OVRCameraRig` results in a runtime error that is thrown from `OVRInput` at line 2154. It can't find the `OVRGamePad` DLL.

Unity Editor is 2017.1.4, Oculus Utilities plugin is 1.27.0. OS is Windows 10.

Comment: Mac or Windows? Is the error happening in the Editor or run-time? I think it would make sense to include the Unity and oculus plugin version in your question

Comment: Updated. The error is runtime.

Comment: Search in your project to see if you have OVRPlugin.dll. You should have one at `<Project>\Assets\Oculus\VR\Plugins\1.27.0\Win` and another one at `<Project>\Assets\Oculus\VR\Plugins\1.27.0\Win64`. Select the dll from the Win folder and make sure that the CPU is set to x86. Select the dll from the Win64 folder and make sure that the CPU is set to x86_64.

Comment: Strangely, the run-time error disappeared when I added the Oculus SDK to the Android build settings and compiled.